# why vim plugin 'itchyny/lightline.vim' colorscheme doesn't change when starting vim?

Tags: vim, settings, vim-plugin

I'm using vim on Mac OS, and installed 'itchyny/lightline.vim' plugin.

As I expect, adding

```sh
let g:lightline = {
  \ 'colorscheme': 'wombat',
  \ }
```

should change my lightline colorscheme to 'wombat', but it doesn't work when I start vim.

But if i do something, like `:PluginInstall`, its colorscheme changes.

How can I change my vim-lightline to always show 'wombat' colorscheme?

Below is my **.vimrc**.

```
set nocompatible

filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim

call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plugin 'itchyny/lightline.vim'

call vundle#end()

filetype plugin indent on

syntax on

set number
set title
set showmatch
set ruler
set ignorecase
set hlsearch
set encoding=utf-8
set termencoding=utf-8
set nobackup
set nowrap
set wmnu

set t_Co=256

set autoindent
set smartindent
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set smarttab
set expandtab
set cursorline

set updatetime=100

set laststatus=2

let g:lightline = {
  \ 'colorscheme': 'wombat',
  \ }

set background=dark
colorscheme default
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got both `airline` and `lightline` listed in your plugins section. Try commenting out or removing `airline` and see if there's any improvement.